# Reflect directory structure in IntelliJ IDEA project view?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to Java and now I need to support a huge Java/maven legacy project. The project sources look like this:

```
projectA
  projectA-part1
    src
    pom.xml
  projectA-part2
    projectA-part2-core
      src
      pom.xml
    projectA-part2-lib1
      src
      pom.xml
projectB
  src
  pom.xml
...
```

So it may contain projects, sub-projects, sub-sub-projects and so on with any number of nesting. But when I try to import this projects to IntelliJ IDEA, it flattens projects tree to only one level of nesting, and all Project view looks messy. Can I preserve the original directory structure in Project view or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Usually a project doesn't contain other projects. It can, however, contain **packages**. It might work if you remove the files and folders concerning the sub-projects, but no guarantees.

Comment: @Aloso By sub-projects I mean logical connection, not any java-specific issue or build dependency. There are originally only maven projects. For me it is not important if they will be imported as packages, modules or something else as long as all maven projects can be compiled and original grouping is preserved.

Comment: What you want should work out of the box regarding projects with multiple modules, and I've worked on many such projects. Did you import the maven projects recursively (there's a checbox somewhere in the wizard)? Also what version are you using and could you show us a screenshot (obviously with sensitive data anonymized with some black rectangles, blurring, etc)?